# Maximum temperature possible on earth on a day

Tags: meteorology, atmosphere, temperature

What is maximum temperature that can we have on earth on a single day?

I assume that after a certain limit, radiation and convection would start working strongly to have equilibrium of surroundings.

According to thermodynamics principles how high temp in theory can go before equalization process restrict any further increase?

Highest I found till now was 58 ℃
in Libya.

This is theoretical question lets say an Air mass stays over an area and sun radiation is also highest how hot it can get

Comment: Is this a question about theory or practice? Please [edit] and make that clear (e.g. in the title).

Comment: @JanDoggen Somebody edited the question yesterday to answer your query, but the editor was not the original author! Since the editor appeared to be guessing at the author's intent, I rejected the edit.

Comment: ...and the edit is approved. @uncia are you the original author under a different name? If not, this edit should not have been approved as it was guessing at the author's intent.

Comment: yep I am original author

Answer (score 5):

Maximum temperature over what area? There are of course local hot spots at hydrothermal and volcanic centers which far exceed the generally excepted maximum recorded temperature, of 58 deg C in Libya (as you correctly state). Many other high temperature anomalous areas exist in areas where there are no met sites to record them. For example, in the Afar triangle depression in the horn of Africa, or in the foothills of the Jebel Akhdar in Oman. In the latter case the steep slopes of black harzburgite rock re-radiates high summer insolation to well into the 50s, but as far as I know, the maximum temperature has never been investigated. Then there is the time-scale. Global warming will almost certainly increase the maximum recorded temperatures over the coming decades and centuries.

On the geological time scale, the sun's radiance is very slowly increasing, so it is only a matter of time (billions of years) before the planet gets so hot that photosynthesis will cease - in which case whatever humanity evolves into will eventually fry.